# Вложенные методы(forEach)

Tags: javascript, методы

```
function longest(s1, s2) {
  let res=""
 return (s1+s2)
   .split("")
   .sort()
   .forEach((item, index, array)=>{
   item!==array[index-1]?res+=item:""
   })
}
console.log(longest("aretheyhere", "yestheyarehere"))
```

Добрый, подскажите, что делаю не так:
Задача следующая - *Возьмите 2 строки s1 и s2, включающие только буквы от a до z. Возвращает новую отсортированную строку, максимально длинную, содержащую различные буквы - каждая из которых берется только один раз.*
Я уже решил ее через цикл for, но хотелось бы через методы и на последнем методе forEach он мне выдает undefined, с чем это связано?

Comment: Обратите внимание на другой ответ с Set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) - ничего не возвращает, именно поэтому в результате кода в вопросе получается `undefined`.

Вместо этого возвращать надо было `res` в которую и собирается результат

```js
function longest(s1, s2) {
  let res = "";
  (s1 + s2)
  .split("")
    .sort()
    .forEach((item, index, array) => {
      item !== array[index - 1] ? res += item : ""
    })
  return res;
}
console.log(longest("aretheyhere", "yestheyarehere"))
```

Comment: Условный оператор "?" подразумевает другой вариант использоваения: result = условие ? значение1 : значение2; т.е. res += item !== array[index - 1] ? item : "";

Comment: @Виктор, почему ты так думаешь? :-)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо! читал  этот момент, но не обратил внимания(

Comment: @Grundy Ну так в синтаксисе команды описано в доке. Так тоже работать будет конечно, но всё таки.

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не реализовать задачу про множества через множества?

```js
function longest(s1, s2) {
    return Array.from(new Set(s1 + s2)).sort().join('');
}

console.log(longest("aretheyhere", "yestheyarehere"))
```

Comment: потому что с `new Set` не знаком еще. Спасибо за вариант!